# An extension of Morera's Theorem

Tags: cv.complex-variables, analytic-functions

Morera's Theorem states that

> If $f$ is continuous in a region $D$ and satisfies $\oint_{\gamma} f = 0$ for 
>   any closed curve $\gamma$ in $D$, then $f$ is analytic in $D$.

I have two questions:

1. If $f$ is continuous in $D$ and  $\oint_C f = 0$ for any circle $C$ in $D$,
   can we deduce that $\oint_{\gamma} f = 0$ for any closed curve $\gamma$ in $D$?
2. (more ambitiously) If  $f$ is continuous and  $\oint_C f = 0$ for any circle $C$ in $D$, is $f$ analytic in $D$ ?

Partial ansers for question 2 seem to be [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MorerasTheorem.html), but I  doubt their argument, specificly, the construction of the original function.

Comment: Number 2 doesn't seem more ambitious to me in light of Morera's theorem.

Comment: Some googling reveals http://anhngq.wordpress.com/2009/07/20/a-generalization-of-the-morera%E2%80%99s-theorem/

Comment: @Sean: Very nice proof on that webpage. I suggest that you add your comment as an answer, because it really answers the original question.

Comment: "If $\oint_\gamma f=0$ for any closed curve $\gamma$" is ambiguous.  A reasonable reader could think it means "If there is any closed curve $\gamma$ for which $\oint_\gamma f=0$".  But I don't think that's what was intended in this case.  Simply changing "any" to "every" would disambiguate it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is yes, and a proof can be found for example on this webpage: http://anhngq.wordpress.com/2009/07/20/a-generalization-of-the-morera%E2%80%99s-theorem/

A brief summary: Suppose $f$ is continuous and $\int_C f = 0$ for every circle $C$, but $\int_\gamma f \neq 0$ for some closed curve $\gamma$. By convolving $f$ with a smooth approximation to the identity, we may assume $f$ is smooth. But then by applying Green's formula to $\int_C f = 0$ for small circles $C$, we see that $f$ must satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations, so $\int_\gamma f = 0$, a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks. The proof seems smooth, but how do you prove you can interchange the order of integration in the 4th formula of that proof ?

Comment: Fubini's theorem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini's_theorem) states that interchanging the order of integration is nice and friendly.

Comment: Surely, I know. Is that function Lebesgue integrable over $\mathbb{C}\times C$ ?

Comment: Just take $\phi$ (the approximation to the identity) to be compactly supported, and then it's obvious, as $\mathbb{C}\times C$ can be replaced in that equation throughout by $\text{supp}\,\phi\times C$.

Comment: Sorry, my question was not well-posed. The correct question is: since $z-w$ would go over circles everywhere in $\mathbb{C}$ as $w$ go over $\mathbb{C}$, so we must require the function be integrable over $\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}$ instead of $\mathbb{C}\times C$. How do we prove this ? It's easy to prove it is locally integrable in $\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @booksee Let me try to clarify my previous comment. If $\phi$ is assumed from the outset to be supported on a compact set $K$ (which is easily arranged), then the relevant equation begins $\int_C f_\epsilon(z)\,dz = \int_C \int_{\epsilon K} f(z-w)\phi_\epsilon(w)\,dw\,dz$. Now there is no possible complaint about changing the order of integration here because we have a jointly continuous function over the compact product $C\times(\epsilon K)$.

Comment: A jointly function is the point sweeping away my doubts. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 11):

First of all, your questions 1 and 2 are equivalent (by the usual Morera theorem).

Second, even stronger generalizations of Morera are available (one does not need all circles).
There is an old nice survey of Zalcman, Offbeat Integral Geometry, in the Monthly.
In particular it contains the following result for the case $D=C$: if the integrals over all
circles of two fixed radii $r_1$ and $r_2$ are zero, then the function is analytic,
unless the ratio of these radii is a zero of Bessel's function $J_1$.
On some more modern research on the topic, I recommend the papers of Hansen, Nadirashvili
and Tumanov   MR2046196.

Comment: Thanks a lot but is the deduction after formula (3) wrong in Zalcman's paper? $\int_C fds\neq \int_0^{2\pi} f(z+re^{i\theta}) d\theta$.

Comment: btw, the world is so small that we're in the same building...

Comment: I am glad to now this:-)